# Deleting object from mongoose database not working if site is not refreshed

Tags: node.js, mongoose

```
app.delete("/api/persons/:id", (req, res, next) => {
 Person.findByIdAndDelete(req.params.id)
.then((result) => {
  res.status(204).end();
})
.catch((error) => next(error));
```

});

Not sure how to even explain this properly, but there is my delete method. It works fine for objects that are allready in the databases, but if I add a new one and I dont refresh the site, I get error: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "undefined" (type string) at path "_id" for model "Person"
Below is my mongoose schema if that helps:

```
const personSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
 name: { type: String, required: true },
 number: { type: Number, required: true },
 });

personSchema.set("toJSON", {
 transform: (document, returnedObject) => {
 returnedObject.id = returnedObject._id.toString();
 delete returnedObject._id;
 delete returnedObject.__v;
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is you're optimistically updating your frontend with the new Person without waiting for a successful DB response with the new data.  That is a valid technique, but gets you into trouble if you're not careful.

My suggestion would be to also send the new value from the database back to your app right away say it can stay in sync.  You likely have no `_id` value on the front end if you're optimistically updating the app before a DB response.

Something like this:

```
app.post("api/person/new", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const person = new Person(req.body)
    await person.save()
    res.status(201).send({ person })
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).send({ err })
  }
})
```

And then more importantly, your API handler on the frontend needs to take that returned `person` value and use it to update the values on your front end, so it has access to the `_id` property for immediate deletion.  And if there's an error creating the person for any reason, you can remove the person from the front end, or handle it however you wish.

I don't know what your app is built with, so I can write a sample bit of code for it.

Comment: Ahhh I see. That was the problem. The front end did not have access to the _id. Thank you for well explained answer :)